# Connecting RFID Scanner, Display, weigh sensor and wifi shield to raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect multiple devices to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. The components are RFID RC522, RPi LCD display, Load Sensor (strain gauge), and WiFi shield. All those are needed for my project. However GPIO pins overlap almost in every case. I do know that we can parallel the Voltage pin, however I'm super confused how to connect all of it on 1 board. If there's a channel splitter hardware solution or an extended version of RPi or in few words - what's the best way to do it - if possible. Thanks!

[image: RFID]

[image: DISPLAY]

I couldn't find the right pictures for weigh sensor with HX711 and wifi shield, but all those need pins.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into the MCP3008 ADC (analog to digital converter) as the raspberry pi has no analog gpio pins and it will allow you up to 8 analog sensors to be attached via 4 wires to the Rpi using SPI, For powering things use a breadboard rail to power your sensors from the Rpi but other gpio pins output 3.3v, to get more gpio pins use an MCP23008 chip through I2C.  if you're using a Rpi 3 it has built in wifi or you can get a usb wifi antenna.